# jQuery UI Reizable sizing issue with box-sizing:border-box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I've issue with Jquery UI Resizable with box-sizing: border-box.
If you remove the box-sizing it will work as expected.

1. Click to make resizable
2. The input element will display wrong size.

Please help me check the issue.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhNpI.jpg

HTML:

```
<button id="resizeBtn">Make Resizable</button>

<div class="canvas ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-selectee" id="56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2" style="position: absolute; top: 77px; left: 242px;">
    <div style="padding: 5px; border-radius: 7px; cursor: default;" class="elementContainer ui-selectee">
        <label class="canvas-span ui-resizable-autohide ui-resizable ui-selectee" id="label_56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2">Click here to change
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e ui-selectee" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s ui-selectee" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-selectee" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
        </label>
        <input style="width: 200px; height: 30px; display: block; margin: 0px; position: relative; zoom: 1; top: auto; left: auto;" class="k-textbox ui-selectee" id="input_56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#resizeBtn').click(function() {
    $("#input_56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2").resizable();
});
```

CSS:

```
/*** reset style from bootstrap***/
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*****Custome style *****/
.canvas {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This is link sample for above code: http://jsfiddle.net/73amaegf/1/

Comment: Set a `height`... `box-sizing` set a size independently the padding

Comment: Thank @LuisP.A. ! Can you update your solution in jsfidddle ?

Comment: You should make the  jsfiddle, then if needed update, we will do

Comment: @LuisP.A. I've provided jsfiddle link above: http://jsfiddle.net/73amaegf/1/

Comment: I update your jsfiddle..and give the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a minimum height for the input element that's being made resizable - add `min-height` to match the height you are setting:

```
<input style="width: 200px; height: 30px; min-height: 30px; display: block; margin: 0px; position: relative; zoom: 1; top: auto; left: auto;" class="k-textbox ui-selectee" id="input_56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2" />
```

To retain exactly the same dimensions, you might want to add `min-width` as well.

### EDIT

So normally if you wanted to mirror dynamic sizing, you would have to do something in jQuery like:

```
$('#resizeBtn').click(function () {
    var theInput = $('#input_56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2');

    $(theInput).css({
        'min-width': $(theInput).outerWidth(),
        'min-height': $(theInput).outerHeight()
    });
    $(theInput).resizable();
});
```

however, in this case adding the below to the CSS:

```
.canvas * {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

does the trick.

Comment: Thank for help, but my input element is dynamic size it will change when drag the icon resize handler and style (width, height, ...) Jquery UI will automatic update to inline style. I don't think this is best solution for this issue.

Comment: The input style inline is dynamic it not fixed width: 200px height: 30px. I think will need other solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i Upadte your jsfiddle

**CSS**

```
input.k-textbox{
    height: 30px !important; // Adjust your needs    
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/73amaegf/5/)**

Comment: Thank for help but It raises a problem: Can't change the height when dragging resize icon.

Comment: It´s a `input` (means one line), maybe what you want is `textarea` (multiple lines)

Comment: My input is one line but need change the size :)

Comment: @TienNguyen instead of `height`set `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

you need to give min-height:30px; to input box. but remember one thing input will get cut less than 30px in height.
[find fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73amaegf/7/)

```
 <input class="k-textbox ui-selectee" id="input_56cec649-f945-4f7e-87bd-c95abcae95e7_ui-id-2" />

.k-textbox{
 width: 200px; min-height: 30px; display: block; margin: 0px; position:  relative; zoom: 1; top: auto; left: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
 box-sizing:content-box;
}
```